# How to wrap and overload all member functions (from an unknown class) at compile time using c++ metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, metaprogramming

Let's say we have a `class A` (which we're not allowed to modify) and want to **wrap all member functions** with new glue code to decide behavior.

```
struct A {
    int foo(){ return a; }
    int bar(){ return b; }
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
}
```

How would we be able to **wrap any class T** (which could have multiple methods) to call into `T` only if conditions are met(ie. a pointer is not null).

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapped {
    Wrapped(T* t): _t(t){ }
    int foo(){ return (_t == nullptr ? 0 : _t->foo()); }
    int bar(){ return (_t == nullptr ? 0 : _t->bar()); }
    T* _t;
}
```

The **use case** is that we could be able to manipulate `Wrapped<A>` as if it was `A` safely:

```
auto a1 = A();
a1.foo(); // 1

auto a2 = Wrapped<A>(new A());
a2.foo(); // 1

auto a3 = Wrapped<A>(nullptr);
a3.foo(); // 0
```

Other notes:

- We wouldn't want to have to write a new specialized `Wrapper` for each possible class that could be wrapped.
- I am aware of things like `shared_ptr<>` exist, but I am trying to insert custom behavior **in-between accessing the class and the method call itself**.
- I would like this to be as *lightweight* as possible in terms of performance.
- If possible, no huge dependency(ie. Boost)

**Any suggestions or pointing in the right direction are appreciated!**

Answer (score 3):

C++ currently lacks the required reflection mechanism to implement something like this satisfying all your requirements.

There is no way to obtain a list of member function names of a class and the only way of "forwarding" member function calls without knowing the member function names is `operator->` as the standard library smart pointers do, which apparently you don't consider sufficient for your purposes.

You need to either modify the original classes themselves to offer reflection information or you need to write wrappers for each class individually (or at least list all possible member function names).

There is currently a draft for a Reflection TS (Technical Specification, i.e. an experimental extension to C++) that would allow one to reflect and obtain the names of member functions, but it still wouldn't allow using these reflected names to declare entities with these names from what I can tell and would therefore still not be enough to solve your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have looked into overloading the `operator->` but as you stated, you don't get the function names. The only thing I've thought about, would be to have the function names in the template like so: `Wrapper<A> a(new A()); a.call<fn>()` where you would be able to retrieve the function name. This way you could cast it before using but it seems like the ugliest thing to use.

Comment: @user2888798 You cannot use member function names like this (I assume you intend `fn` to be the function name). The only thing you can do is pass a member function pointer: `a.call<&A::fn>()` and only if `fn` is not overloaded in `A`.

Comment: Oups, yes sorry, I just thought this is the closest idea of how to do it, and I really don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article by B. Stroustrup, ["Wrapping C++ Member Function Calls
"](http://stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf), which describes a general method. The abtract says:

> This paper presents a simple, general, and efficient solution to the old problem of ‘‘wrapping’’ calls to an object in pairs of prefix and suffix code. The solution is also non-intrusive, applies to existing classes, allows the use of several prefix/suffix pairs, [...]

IIRC, Stroustrup's wrapper is somewhat like a smart pointer, and it runs code in its `operator->()` and runs some other code after running the wrapped object's function (see the article for details). This approach has *several* limitations, see the end of the article.

Depending on your exact needs, you might be able to use this approach. In your example, the wrapper is just *return 0 in every function if wrapped is nullptr*, so it might work. For more complex behaviour, it may not.

*Update*: See @Jarod42's answer. Stroustrup's wrapper is a more elaborate version of that. For your case/example, when wrapping `nullptr` `operator->()` might return a pointer to some other given fixed instance.

Answer (score -1):

Not ideal in your case, but `operator->` might help:

```
template<class T>
struct Wrapped {
    Wrapped(T* t): _t(t){ }

    const T* operator -> () const { if (_t == nullptr) throw std::logic_error("null pointer"); return _t; }
    T* operator -> () { if (_t == nullptr) throw std::logic_error("null pointer"); return _t; }

    T* _t;
};
```

it forwards to any member. it allows to have code before and or after (with extra RAII) the call.

Comment: Wouldn't this throw exceptions if the thing is invalid(nullptr)? I am trying to prevent this and return a `Wrapped<T>` which could be used the same way as `T` without crashing when calling into it. I also wouldn't want to wrap every call with *try{} catch{}* statements.

Comment: Yes, it throws in case of invalid data. I don't think you can do better in generic case anyway: for methods which return reference, you cannot return default value, that also true for non default constructible type.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider the use of an optional value with `std::optional<T>`:

```
const A defaultA{ 0, 0 };   // set the default values that must be returned

std::optional<A> foo(int x)
{
    auto opt = std::optional<A>();
    if (x >= 0)
        opt.emplace();
    return opt;
}

int main()
{
    auto a1 = foo(-1);      // returns an optional with no value
    std::cout << a1.value_or(defaultA).foo() << std::endl; // 0 (foo is called on defaultA)
    std::cout << (a1?a1->bar():0)            << std::endl; // 0

    auto a2 = foo(4);       // returns an optional with a value
    std::cout << a2.value_or(defaultA).foo() << std::endl; // 1 
    std::cout << a2.value_or(defaultA).bar() << std::endl; // 2
}
```

For more information about `std::optional<T>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Hope this helps.